# Do occasional improved periods of breathing indicate that rapid breathing is not due to decreased lung capacity?

Tags: dogs

We have a boxer diagnosed with lymphoma in the lung a few months back.  But she has been responding well to prednisone since then.

Over the past weeks, breathing has increased [typically reaching sleeping rates of around 65 breaths per minute].

But there are also times where for a few minutes (both when sleeping and when up and about), she will settle into longer deeper breaths [nearer 35 breaths per minute].

Do these deeper breathing periods generally exclude actual physical limitation of lung volume [probably from the cancer] as being the direct cause of the tachypnea, or is there generally significant variability in breathing even in such circumstances?

Comment: I'm really asking this to be of more general value, as such indications might be useful to many in a variety of circumstance.

Comment: But if specific details are wished for: 8 year old, in recent weeks has also developed right side facial paralysis and a mix of cutaneous and subcutaneous bumps mostly around the abdomen. Still only right mandibular lymph swollen, very occasional coughing has returned. Generally lethargic and not as excited by her food, but still energized by walks, "people food", and human interactions. Recent treatment aimed at the paralysis of steroid, decongestant, and vitamin B injections, along with a baytril regimen, hasn't helped with any of the ailments (eyedrops have helped maintain eye usability).

Comment: Finances dictate that expected values where thousands of dollars is spent for life extension of a few months is too extreme. Our current vet has fostered growing doubts after repeated unthorough examinations and a pattern of pushing marked up medication rather than writing prescriptions. So a better insight into whether this is likely the ultimately incurable cancer or whether this instead points more towards alternatives (fluid/mucous buildup, heart failure, other body stress/discomforts, etc) that may be fairly economically treated for a while, is very useful information here.

Comment: And hopefully this question will give a foundation to help others make similar choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sad to hear your dog is diagnosed with lymphoma :(

Regarding the breathing rates, you need to consider the difference between oxygenation and heat regulation.

There is an inevitable decrease of lung volume, which shows by the increase of 'average' respiration rate, when your animal needs to oxygenate and heat regulate.  There are these moments when only oxygenation is needed, those are the moments when resp rate drops.  But the lung volume is still decreased, unfortunately.  The animal just needs less 'flow'.

KR

Hewi

Answer (score 0):

I'm marking Hewi's answer as correct, was good information.  But in case anyone else is seeking something concrete, here is the followup with our own results...

Here was Hanna's x-ray four months ago:
[image: then]

I'm not even a world close to a radiologist.  I wish there was more out there to understand it online, but unfortunately the resources are pretty paltry.  But as I understand it, you're aiming to look for black as healthy lung tissue.  White can be other things causing a poor picture... you're really looking towards more subtle shapes for problems, as I'll make clearer below.  But you really want to see lots of good black.

Now the x-ray this week:
[image: now]

I think you can pretty clearly see the answer to my question was: no... despite occasional longer breaths, it can still be an indication that it is really bad.

The side view might help see more into the explanation to why I believe:
[image: now2]

From what we were shown by the vet and can see here, it's pretty clear the problem... it's the small "cannonball" spots that are the ugliness...

[image: now2more]

Those red circles identify just some of them I'm thinking.

Unfortunately it just doesn't work like I'd imagined when I asked the question.  It isn't all about one big growth surging through the lungs cutting down volume and making breaths shorter and shorter.  It's often a growing horde of masses doing the damage collectively. :-(

Perhaps laying just right, things settle just enough to get a few good breaths.  Because it wasn't a mass that was taking up her whole long.  It was a bunch of them spread out.  And they're generally going to just make it worse and worse until it reaches the end of the road if the feasible treatments have run out.

So again, the answer is clearly: **even occasional deep breaths don't do anything to rule out the awful spread of cancer in the lungs.**

I'm certainly sorry if you're having to go through this.  I know too well.  Life is too brutally short.

Remember how short it is always.